# How to write inline like operator with Variable value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-like

I have the following query, can you please suggest me what is wrong with this, its never entering inside the `IF` block, even though data is present in a table.

```
 DECLARE @AccountNumber NVARCHAR(50) ='54654654'

 IF Exists( Select TOP 1 1 FROM [dbo].[CheckRecords] where DetailRecord like '% ' + @AccountNumber +' %')
 BEGIN
     Print 'Hello' + @AccountNumber 
 END
```

Comment: You can try `DECLARE @AccountNumber NVARCHAR(50) ='% 54654654 %'`

Comment: Infact I tried that , its still not entering inside IF Block

Comment: You need to show some sample data from the table because the logic is right... that is assuming your search is surrounded by spaces as shown? You can remove `top 1` though because `exists` doesn't require a single record.

Answer (score 1):

```
 DECLARE @AccountNumber NVARCHAR(50) ='54654654'
 IF Exists( Select TOP 1 1 FROM [dbo].[CheckRecords] 
 where DetailRecord like '%'  + @AccountNumber +'%')
     BEGIN
         Print 'Hello ' + @AccountNumber 
     END
```

try this it will work. it was not working because of extra space.

Comment: Thank you for the response, it worked but above query taking almost 50 seconds to complete , Can you please suggest me if there is any better way of writing same logic ?

Comment: replace of exists , you can use not null function